# CORS policy in AWS Elastic beanstalk and S3 static web

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm using nodejs as backend and host it in AWS. I did this configuration in node project:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS"
  );
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
    "true"
  );
  next();
});
```

The frontend which is hosted in S3 bucket, is created with Ionic angular. And here is its configuration in and interceptor:

```
  req = req.clone({
     setHeaders : {
         Authorization: "Bearer " + userToken,
         'Content-Type': `application/json; charset=utf-8`
         }
  });
```

In the S3 bucket (which hosted the frontend), I added this configuration in CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>http://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

When I run the app locally and connect it to the backend via proxy, it works without any problem. But when I upload it and try to connect to the backend I get the error:

*"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource."*

What is left in my configuration and how to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

For the local environment, you need to use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-cors-access-control/lhobafahddgcelffkeicbaginigeejlf?hl=en) plugin for chrome browser. After installed you need to enable it then it will work fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I cannot ask all users to install this plugin for their browsers.

Comment: This is only for the local environment. On the live site, your code will working fine.

Comment: For local as long as I use proxy, I have no problem. My problem is that my code doesn't work on the live site!

Comment: Can you please append "Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" and "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest" in the HttpHeaders() ?

Comment: I did. But unfortunately didn't solve the problem:    Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: Okay, then can you please set this "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" in your backend technology?

Comment: If you have a look on my code you can see it's already there:    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208552/discussion-between-aman-gojariya-and-amin).